Any consensus on Łukasiewicz' idea that Aristotle's syllogisms were systematically misrepresented in the academic literature?
Is there a consensus today on Jan Łukasiewicz' 1957 assertion that Aristotle's syllogisms were systematically misrepresented in the academic literature?
Łukasiewicz, in Aristotle's Syllogistic from the Standpoint of Modern Formal Logic (1957), claims that Aristotle's syllogisms are not of the form usually found in the academic literature as:

All men are mortal; Socrates is a man; therefore Socrates is mortal.

but instead, only involve conditionals:

If all men are mortal and all Greeks are men, then all Greeks are mortal.

Thank you for any scholarly references.

No; for modern discussion concerning A's syllogism see Corcoran-Smiley interpretation.

Timothy Smiley, What is a syllogism? (JournaI of Philosophical Logic, 1973) and John Corcoran, Aristotelian Syllogisms: Valid Arguments or True Universalized Conditionals? (Mind, 1974)

Łukasiewicz's interpretation is discussed in SEP:"Łukasiewicz’s trenchant and controversial views sparked a controversy... While the principles did win an early adherent in Patzig (1968), subsequent criticisms by Corcoran (1972, 1974) and, independently, Smiley (1974) established clearly that syllogisms are not propositions but inferences, and that Aristotle had no need of a prior logic of propositions." Read criticizes the Corcoran-Smiley interpretation as well, on other grounds.
